# How to use Implicit optional for a delegate

Tags: scala

I want to use implicits for Dependency injection, in my code I want to provide a default implementation but I want to give the person who might use my Class to inject its own implementation but I can't figure out best way to do it.

General is something likes this

```
class ClassA {
   val something : ClassB = new ClassB()

   something.eventAdapter(new MyDefaultImplementation())
}

class MyDefaultImplementation(implicit specificImplementation: EventAdapter[EventA, EventB] = null) extends EventAdapter[EventA, EventB] {
    override def doSomething(event: EventA) : EventB = {
        if(specificImplementation != null) {
           specificImplementation.doSomething(event)
        } else {
           event match {
             case _ => new EventB()
           }
        }
    }
}
```

and if some other developer want to provide another implementation.

```
object OtherDeveloperImplementation {
    implicit val otherImplementation = OtherDeveloperImplementation()
}

class OtherDeveloperImplementation extends extends EventAdapter[EventA, EventB] {
    override def doSomething(event: EventA) : EventB = {
        convert(event)
    }
}
```

My dilemma is, I don't know what the other developer will call his class, so I can't make an import in 'ClassA' something like the following.

```
class ClassA {
   import OtherDeveloperImplementation._
   val something : ClassB = new ClassB()

   something.eventAdapter(new MyDefaultImplementation())
}
```

because I don't know how the developer name his class, how should I deal with this?

Thx for answers

Comment: First thing to do is get rid of that `null` and use a default implementation instead, and remove that bogus `match` that does nothing. Generally this example could be significantly simplified.

Comment: This is just sample code to show what I am trying to do, my real code has nothing to do with this sample code.

Comment: The trouble is that it is difficult to tell which bits of this code are relevant to the question and which are not. For example, what is that `match` for? Why isn't `EventAdapter` defined? Why does it take type parameters? What is `ClassB` for if the code just calls a method on it?